# Retrieve ID of *ngFor elements in a table - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-directive, ngfor

I have a table wherein I've iterated 3 FA-icons inside `Button` tag using `*ngFor`, like the image shown here.

[image: Table]

I have given the 3 buttons separate IDs(viz. 1,2&3) to note which button is clicked. The buttons are Add, Edit and Delete. Although I'm sending it's ID through (click) event to the component. The function is not able to retrieve the ID every time the button is clicked. It retrieves the ID after random multiple clicks and not each time the button is clicked. I don't understand why it's behaving like this.

**HTML:**

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let ABC of XYZ">
      <td>{{ABC.Records}}}</td>
      <td>
           <button id="1" (click)="fun($event)"><fa-icon [icon]="plussquare"></fa-icon></button>
           <button id="2" (click)="fun($event)" ><fa-icon [icon]="editfa"></fa-icon></button>
           <button id="3" (click)="fun($event)" ><fa-icon [icon]="trashfa"></fa-icon></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**.TS:**

```
fun($event:any){
     console.log($event.target.id)
 }
```

All add buttons should have id 1, edit buttons should have id 2 and 3 for delete buttons.

Comment: Not sure if this is the whole answer or not, but IDs should be unique, so if each row's buttons have the same ID as the buttons in the other rows, that's gonna be a problem. Try changing the IDs to have the row number in there too, so every button in the table ends up with a different ID.

Comment: Even if I set `value` attribute as add, edit & delete, it still randomly retrieves the value. So even if ID should be unquie, `value` attribute should at least work but it's not the case.

Comment: Why not fun(ABC, ‘edit’) etc..?

Comment: Thanks @MikeOne, your comment also works like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you not just need 3 methods ?

```
 funEdit($event:any, yourVar){
     console.log($event.target.id)
 }
funAdd($event:any, yourVar){
         console.log($event.target.id)
}
funDelete($event:any, yourVar){
         console.log($event.target.id)
}
```

That you will use like it :

```
<button (click)="funAdd($event,ABC)"><fa-icon [icon]="plussquare"></fa-icon></button>
<button (click)="funEdit($event,ABC)" ><fa-icon [icon]="editfa"></fa-icon></button>
<button (click)="funDelete($event,ABC)" ><fa-icon [icon]="trashfa"></fa-icon></button>
```

And passing your ABC var in second params to know the line